# how to write inline [ngStyle] for complex multiple conditions in angular2

Tags: angular, ng-class, ng-style

Here, I want to pass a condition in div that when it contains a certain number display certain color.

The condition is:

```
      if (num >= -100.0 && num <= -35.0) {
          return '#f1403b';
        } else if (num > -35.0 && num <= 35.0) {
          return '#ffc200';
        } else {
          return '#34A853';
        }

app.component.html
---------------------
 <div  [ngStyle]="{'color': (num >= '-100.0' && num <= '-35.0' ) ? '#f1403b' : ( (num > '-35.0' && num <= '35.0') ? '#ffc200' :'#34A853')
}">
({{num}})
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to inline it? Just put that logic in the component class and expose it via a `get` accessor.

Comment: My requirement is to pass an inline css with above condition. If it is possible, please help.

Comment: But **why do you want to write it inline?!** Where does that requirement come from? You're just going to end up with a very complex expression in your template, when it is completely unnecessary - the same functionality can be achieved in other, more readable ways.

Comment: Assign the result of the expression to a field and use the field as condition.

Comment: I want to pass the expression condition in ngStyle inline. If it is possible.

Comment: Please stop just saying the same thing over and over again. **Why?** Why *specifically* do you want to try to jam this all into the template? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Why not just use a field, as Günter and I have suggested?

Comment: Please stop just asking the same thing over and over again. I have mentioned the scenario and want the answer in the same context as asked, If answer is possible . I know, the asked solution is not the best solution to deal with but I dont need the best.

Comment: @ManzerHashmi it's not that you don't want the best. It's the you're specifically asking experts here how to do things in a horrible, shitty way, and are refusing to give a rational reason why. People answering here take pride in what they do, and won't advise you to do things in such a horrible way. So you can just assume it's not possible, and move on to solve a real problem.

Answer (score 7):

Hello You can define a function in controller which returns the value of your needs. You can use that in view file.
Below I am giving a plunker link . Just go through it. Hope it will work for you. Let me know if you have any doubts on this. 
[https://plnkr.co/edit/lW1rP9VyCeqpS5QhGjJA?p=preview](http://plunker)

Codes:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'color': colorGreen(), 'font-size': size + 'px', 'font-weight': 'bold'}">
```

Angular 2 Ng Style Example

You can check your if() condition here and return the color.

```
colorGreen = function(){
return 'green';
}
```

Thanks